# Pre remove item event

Tags: sharepoint-designer, item, delete

I'm using sharepoint 2013,
I want to do someting before I delete item from my list.

It's imposable in nintex.

How can I catch the event?

Thanks

Comment: Which SharePoint server you are using? Is it SharePoint 2013 server or Office365 or SharePoint 2010? Please raise your question with proper details. Please refer this link: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of event receiver to take appropriate action when item deletion is initiated.

refer below article for more details on implementing event receiver:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/